# how to ignore ssl error on android volley http request?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I am making a TV application which requests m3u8 file via HTTPS. When I run it on Android 4.4, I see some "handshake failed" in logcat. I suspect it is related to SSL validation problems. May I know how to ignore these errors?

I see there are method like writing my own HTTPSTrustManager by extending X509TrustManager. But the code is in JAVA. My application is in Kotlin. I am new to Android development. May anyone please help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use http instead https

Comment: @JuanDanielOrnella no... the m3u8 file is not controllable by me. if I can control it, I'd try to fix all HTTPS error LOL

Comment: May anyone please checkout my project and take a look? It runs well on Lollipop and above, but not on Kitkat 4.4. I think it is due to HTTPS error, but I doubt... https://github.com/y2kbug-hk/dev.thematrix.tvhk

Comment: _"But the code is in JAVA. My application is in Kotlin."_ Android Studio's kotlin plugin can convert Java code to Kotlin for you. Though ignoring errors without even understanding what they mean doesn't sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a self signed certificate using the Volley

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, new HurlStack(null, getSocketFactory()));


    StringRequest s = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,  "https://192.168.1.10:443",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {

                    Log.e("RESULT",s);

                }
            }, 

           new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                     Log.e("RESULTfailder",volleyError.getMessage()); }
          } );

    rq.add(s);
 }


private SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {

       CertificateFactory cf = null;
       try {
           cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
           InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.server);
           Certificate ca;
           try {
               ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
               Log.e("CERT", "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
           } finally {
               caInput.close();
           }


           String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
           KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
           keyStore.load(null, null);
           keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);


           String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
           TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
           tmf.init(keyStore);


           HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
               @Override
               public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

                    Log.e("CipherUsed", session.getCipherSuite());
                    return hostname.compareTo("192.168.1.10")==0; //The Hostname of your server

               }
           };


           HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
           SSLContext context = null;
           context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

           context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
           HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

           SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();


           return sf;

       } catch (CertificateException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return  null;
   }

}
```

Comment: I have commented on my question. May you please take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what's inside R.raw.server? or What kind of file is?